# Using ExpandCollapseCommandName from Parent Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

For those Telerik gurus out there, I have a Hierarchical DataGrid that is created in a class then displayed dynamically to the form. I am unable to get the ExpandCollapseCommandName to work on postback in the ItemCommand Event below.

```
private void ActiveBatchesRadGrid_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExpandCollapseCommandName)
    {
        e.Item.Selected = !e.Item.Expanded;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to GetDataKeyValue() of the parent row when a parent row is expanded.
PS. I know the code above does not give me the DataKeyValue.

Comment: I found the problem. HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.Client should have been set to HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.ServerBind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.Client should have been set to HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.ServerBind